# fadeOut doesn't remove the elements

Tags: jquery, fadeout

I have three of li:

```
<li id="234-sg-235"><div><a></a></li>
<li><div><a></a></li>
<li>
    <div>
        <a>Don't show again</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

it seems something like:
[image]

while the user presses `don't show again`, I want to remove these li-s after 3 seconds.

so I need only the code which removes them.

I tried three things:

**1)**

```
$(this).parent('div').parent('li').fadeOut(3000);
$(this).parent('div').parent('li').prev().fadeOut(3000);
$(this).parent('div').parent('li').prev().prev().fadeOut(3000);
```

**2)**

```
var notificationId = $(this).parent('div').parent('li').prev().prev().attr("id");
$(this).parent('div').parent('li').fadeOut(3000);
$("#" + notificationId).next().fadeOut(3000);
$("#" + notificationId).fadeOut(3000);
```

**3)**

```
$(this).parent('div').parent('li').fadeOut(3000, function () {
    $(this).parent('div').parent('li').remove();
});

$(this).parent('div').parent('li').prev().fadeOut(3000, function () {
    $(this).parent('div').parent('li').prev().remove();
});

$(this).parent('div').parent('li').prev().prev().fadeOut(3000, function () {
    $(this).parent('div').parent('li').prev().prev().remove();
});
```

but the result is (the first li was deleted and the others got: `display:none`):

```
<li style="display: none"><div><a></a></li>
<li style="display: none">
    <div>
        <a>Don't show again</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

why these li-s were not deleted? why the first li is only deleted?

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After

```
$(this).parent('div').parent('li').remove();
```

in the next call

```
$(this).parent('div').parent('li')
```

is already removed. You should reverse the order in which you remove the three `li`'s.

**Edit:** Better solution:

```
$(this).parent('div').parent('li').add($(this).prev().add($(this).prev()).fadeout(3000, function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: You're expecting them to remove synchronously, which is a bad assumption.  It think you'd be better off doing all of the selections, then wrapping those in a closure.

Answer (score 2):

it should be

```
$('ul a').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('li').prevAll(':lt(2)').addBack().fadeOut(3000, function () {
        $(this).remove()
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/K2TC6/)

Comment: Doesn't that also just remove one of the three?

Comment: This would remove only the `third` `li`.

Comment: Sexy, but, what if the triggering `<a>` element will be not in 3rd `<li>`? Or what if the number of `<li>`'s will more than 3? Then you should modify your code. The @Jashwant's awsers is more fexible.

Comment: @ataman if you look at my demo, I designed it to support multiple sets of the same combination

Answer (score 2):

```
var lis = $(this).closest('li').siblings('li').addBack();
lis.fadeOut(3000,function () {
  lis.remove();
});
```

or,

(assuming `ul` is parent of `li`)

```
 $(this).closest('ul').find('li').fadeOut(3000,function () {
   $(this).remove();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
<li id="234-sg-235"><div><a>first li</a></li>
<li><div><a>second li</a></li>
<li>
    <div>
        <a href="#" id="dontshow">Don't show again</a>
    </div>
</li>

$('#dontshow').on('click', function(){
   $("li:has('a')").fadeOut(3000, function () {
        $(this).remove()
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/s3beY/)